# Nulls not appearing when SessionId is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I'm doing the below SQL correctly but apparently not.  My dbo.AttendeesLedger.SessionId is sometimes null, and those null values never appear in the result.

```
SELECT 
  dbo.AttendeesLedger.Id,
  dbo.AttendeesLedger.SessionId,
  dbo.AttendeesLedger.AttendeesId,
  dbo.Attendees.Id,
  dbo.Sessions.Id
FROM
  dbo.AttendeesLedger
  INNER JOIN dbo.Attendees ON (dbo.AttendeesLedger.AttendeesId = dbo.Attendees.Id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sessions ON (dbo.AttendeesLedger.SessionId = dbo.Sessions.Id)
```

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE demonstrating the issue. Works fine [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c733/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known thing with integers. 0 and Null is not the same thing and
because you join to other tables it will not include null unless you explicitly say
it should

Add " or dbo.AttendeesLedger.SessionId is null " to see them.

More details on this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

This might also be of use to you (ANSI_NULLS) :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: thanks:  FROM dbo.AttendeesLedger
         INNER JOIN dbo.Attendees ON (dbo.AttendeesLedger.AttendeesId =
         dbo.Attendees.Id)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sessions ON (dbo.AttendeesLedger.SessionId =
         dbo.Sessions.Id)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `INNER JOIN` is filtering out those results. I mean, the `LEFT JOIN` keeps all the values in the left but the `INNER JOIN` will only keep those values that make the first `ON` condition `true`. Whenever the first condition is `false` then those results will not be displayed... even if you use a `LEFT JOIN` because the unmatched values will no longer be there.

Comment: Based on Martin's fiddle this example would reflect the issue as I understand it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e56a9/1

Comment: Yes, Mosty, that is it.  I'm wanting to show both rows including the null. looks like the fiddle show my problem by resulting 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this query is filtering out the sessions.  So, you should be getting all sessions.

I do note that you can remove the last join; it is not necessary.  If it were an `inner join` instead of a `left outer join` then the query would filter out the NULL session ids.  Or, this might happen with a `where` clause.  But your query is not filtering anything.

You can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT al.Id, al.SessionId, al.AttendeesId, a.Id
FROM dbo.AttendeesLedger al INNER JOIN
     dbo.Attendees a
     ON al.AttendeesId = a.Id;
```

Comment: It's actually a 3 table join.  how are you including the sessions table here?

Comment: @PeterKellner . . . I'm not including it.  It does not seem necessary.  You have a `left outer join`, so all records are being kept.  You are not using any fields from the `sessions` table.  The join isn't necessary.

Comment: my bad, I stripped out most (1 too many) columns to keep the example short.  I did put back in session.id to make it clear I need that table but i really should have made the example session.title to be extra clear.